# Pyautogui isn't communicating with my computer

Tags: python, pyautogui

I made a program for work that does a few things like open webpages or tabs in my work software. It worked totally fine on my first computer, but when I moved the program to my new computer it stopped. There are no errors thrown, but pyautogui wont move the mouse or click anything. I just started coding recently, so it could be a very obvious solution that I'm just missing, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the program I'm trying to use: https://github.com/DaddyChill4205/Stack-Overflow/blob/6a0c1d7bfcd8996ba39d7717f99bd24ca882f6ea/hotkeys_for_joe.pyw

Comment: Rename your file to have a `.py` extension and then launch it from a command prompt: `python hotkeys_for_joe.py`. Then you will see the exception(s) that are generated or other console output that will help you track down the error. I'd guess it's because you're missing some of the files on your new computer or have not installed the required modules. If you [edit] your question to include the error, it might be possible to assist you further.

Comment: @import There are no errors, that's the confusing part. It even gives a return that the image was found, but nothing is ever clicked.